# Do I need to use inject method or I will modify this original hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to update my hash if a specific key in hash is nil. I have to show the plot data coming from hash in a pie chart. But the key is coming as nil. So how can I modify the key which is nil in that hash.This is my Original Hash:

```
{nil=>762, "Bamanpuri Village"=>1, "Charlotte"=>8}
```

Required Hash:

```
{"Others"=>762, "Bamanpuri Village"=>1, "Charlotte"=>8}
```

Do I need to use inject method or I will modify this original hash.

Answer (score 3):

You can do as below :-

```
hash = {nil=>762, "Bamanpuri Village"=>1, "Charlotte"=>8}
hash['Others']= hash.delete(nil) if hash.has_key?(nil)
hash # => {"Bamanpuri Village"=>1, "Charlotte"=>8, "Others"=>762}
```

Answer (score 0):

i was fetching some values from a model and it was giving me a hash. so i applied above suggested solution as:

```
    @k = ScannedQrCodes.group("city").count
    @k['Others'] = @k.delete(nil) if @k.has_key?(nil)
    @result = @k.to_a
```